# Bulk data upload in salesforce with duplicate check

Tags: deployment

I want to upload 1000 Account and Contact records to salesforce. I am not sure how many of them are duplicate. I cant use data loader as it will check the duplicate records in batches, so it will not check the duplicate records in same batch.
Could anyone suggest how can i upload the unique records ?

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, Dataloader does not check for duplicates, the Import Wizard does. Depending on what you want, chose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use Dataloader to prevent duplicates.

You can do things like install a DupeBlocker tool (Look on AppExchange) which can be configured to prevent duplicate records from being insterted into SFDC.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use Salesforce Import Wizard instead of Data Loader.

### [image]

**To prevent duplicates:** Salesforce has introduced out of the box duplicate matching. you can set up those rules in Salesforce keep records unique. It would work with Dataloader as well.

It can be found in set up:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate matching rules are not working in dataloader, if i am selecting dataloader for a batch of more then one then these rules are not working. If i am selecting batch size of 1 then only duplicate rules are working